# How do I make reusable useState and function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make switch buttons and i want to duplicate it with using one useState and one function.
So this is the code :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SettingXY = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const showMenu = e => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
      case "A":
        setState(1);
        break;
      case "B":
        setState(2);
        break;
      case "C":
        setState(3);
        break;
      case "D":
        setState(4);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* first  */}
      <button id="A" onClick={showMenu}>
        A setting
      </button>
      <button id="B" onClick={showMenu}>
        B setting
      </button>
      <button id="C" onClick={showMenu}>
        C setting
      </button>
      <button id="D" onClick={showMenu}>
        D setting
      </button>
      <div>
        {state === 1 && <div state={state}>This is A</div>}
        {state === 2 && <div state={state}>This is B</div>}
        {state === 3 && <div state={state}>This is C</div>}
        {state === 4 && <div state={state}>This is D</div>}
      </div>

      {/* second  */}
      <button id="A" onClick={showMenu}>
        A setting
      </button>
      <button id="B" onClick={showMenu}>
        B setting
      </button>
      <button id="C" onClick={showMenu}>
        C setting
      </button>
      <button id="D" onClick={showMenu}>
        D setting
      </button>
      <div>
        {state === 1 && <div state={state}>This is A</div>}
        {state === 2 && <div state={state}>This is B</div>}
        {state === 3 && <div state={state}>This is C</div>}
        {state === 4 && <div state={state}>This is D</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SettingXY;
```

Both changes at the same time with same thing. so i had to use duplicate useState like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SettingXY = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const [state2, setState2] = useState();

  const showMenu = e => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
      case "A":
        setState(1);
        break;
      case "B":
        setState(2);
        break;
      case "C":
        setState(3);
        break;
      case "D":
        setState(4);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  const showMenu2 = e => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
      case "A":
        setState2(1);
        break;
      case "B":
        setState2(2);
        break;
      case "C":
        setState2(3);
        break;
      case "D":
        setState2(4);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* first  */}
      <button id="A" onClick={showMenu}>
        A setting
      </button>
      <button id="B" onClick={showMenu}>
        B setting
      </button>
      <button id="C" onClick={showMenu}>
        C setting
      </button>
      <button id="D" onClick={showMenu}>
        D setting
      </button>
      <div>
        {state === 1 && <div state={state}>This is A</div>}
        {state === 2 && <div state={state}>This is B</div>}
        {state === 3 && <div state={state}>This is C</div>}
        {state === 4 && <div state={state}>This is D</div>}
      </div>

      {/* second  */}
      <button id="A" onClick={showMenu2}>
        A setting
      </button>
      <button id="B" onClick={showMenu2}>
        B setting
      </button>
      <button id="C" onClick={showMenu2}>
        C setting
      </button>
      <button id="D" onClick={showMenu2}>
        D setting
      </button>
      <div>
        {state2 === 1 && <div state={state2}>This is A</div>}
        {state2 === 2 && <div state={state2}>This is B</div>}
        {state2 === 3 && <div state={state2}>This is C</div>}
        {state2 === 4 && <div state={state2}>This is D</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SettingXY;
```

but what i want to do is just use one `useState` and one function.  and make it DRY
so how can i make reusable `useState`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set id and fetch it via switch case, you just can pass value from state direct like setState(1) and so on...and if you need showMenu you can just pass showMenu("A")...

for your question, if you using one state that's mean you are listening to any change on this state, so that if you have to component/list/items depends on this state will re-render base on it, so that, if you are needed it like this, one state its correct, else two-state is the correct, else one is good...

Now, you can handling your case by made the state object nested of value, for example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ONE: {...}, TWO: {...}})
```

and base on your case, update your target...

But since your function and your code is equal and just the diff is id, replace it to be like this:

```
  {/* first  */}
  <button onClick={() => setState(1) || showMenu("A")}>
    A setting
  </button>
  <button onClick={() => setState(2) || showMenu("B")}>
    B setting
  </button>
  <button onClick={() => setState(3) || showMenu("C")}>
    C setting
  </button>
  <button onClick={() => setState41) || showMenu("D")}>
    D setting
  </button>
```

Note: use setState or showMEnu...Just code to explain what you can do...

via this update, both group one and group two will be updated and display the correct state...

Comment: Oh This is awesome !  thank you very much  !! very helpful !!